# Spark Job crash

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

After working and inserting data for some hours, the spark job crashes, without any configuration or server condition changes.

I'm getting the below stacktrace in the log:

```
> Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.ocp.jfc2.plant.dataprocessor.PlantDataProcessor$2.call(PlantDataProcessor.java:126)
    at com.ocp.jfc2.plant.dataprocessor.PlantDataProcessor$2.call(PlantDataProcessor.java:123)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    ... 2 more
```

Does anybody know why this error happens?

Comment: What Spark version are you using? Is your environment secure?

Comment: Hi , Spark version is 2.3.1